# Twitter Bootstrap 'nav' not working on ie8

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

The class 'nav nav-tabs' is not working in ie8. Any idea how can I make it work?

This is the code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-transclude="" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}" 
    style="width: 600px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">

<!--    ngRepeat: tab in tabs    -->

</ul>
```

Angular provides the tab names, i want it to work on internet explorer 8.

Comment: Possible Fix: http://hands-on-coding.blogspot.in/2014/09/fixing-bootstrap-ie-8-issue-related-to.html

Comment: It's not working in my case. I have tried that already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this issue on the Bootstrap GitHub forums: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6548.

It seems as though native IE8 will sometimes break due to the `filter: parameter` which is used throughout Bootstrap css for gradients etc. The solution is to add `filter:none!important;` to an element like `.navbar` or `.navbar-inner`.